Is overfitting always bad?
I have trained my model for the first time and inference it on random images. When I tried random image that has similar camera position with my dataset, it fits well at detecting river. But when it’s like satellite view or something else, it fails quite bad.
I plot the training stats and here’s the graphs.


The loss is lowering, but the accuracy remains the same more or less. Is this overfitting? Is there a specific statistical method I need to do to interpret these stats? I mean, I want a model that is very specific for this point of view dataset so being able to detect river at that angle is good enough, except the camera suddenly flips or tip like 30 degree, I'm on my way to try that now. But I also know overfitting bad while adding more random data to it will just remade the model to be general although now it’s for river with various angle.
Is this good enough or is there something else I could do to make it better? Thanks in advance for the input

You should use the same distribution for validation that you plan to use in your application. If you avoid contaminating your validation set say with duplicate or very similar images as the training set, then it is fine if your model works only for a very specific distribution, that's the best you can do for your use case.
